# Как сделать приложения youtube downloader на android

Tags: android, youtube

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужно сделать приложения, клиент youtube, чтобы можно было скачать видео.
Я только начал работу над этим проектом. Поэтому не знаю с чего начать как что происходит. Сможете ли описать принцип работы или указать куда копать?
Очень благодарен всем.

Answer (score 3):

1. Находите API YouTube.
2. Изучаете его на предмет наличия методов для получения прямых ссылок на скачивание видео.
3. Встраиваете в приложение кнопки, по нажатию на которые вызываются нужные методы API.

Если API нет - придётся расковыривать сайт и искать там информацию о нужных запросах.

Также следует изучить насколько легально будет сделать ваше приложение. YouTube, насколько я знаю, не разрешает, например, монетизировать к-л образом приложения с контентом с него. Т.е. Google забанит подобные приложения в PlayMarket. На счёт скачивания видео не знаю - изучайте документацию и лицензионные соглашение к нему.

Comment: поучительно. Благодарю